Looking for OR courses on following topics
Currently, I am self-teaching myself the following topics in OR;
a.) Multiobjective optimization,
b.) Deterministic/Probabilistic Inventory models
c.) Deterministic/Stochastic Dynamic Programming.
On Coursera, I was able to find a course on Discrete Optimization, which is heavily focused on Constraint Programming. I am not too much focused on it.
If possible, can I get recommendations on online courses for the above topics? It will be helpful if the videos are more math-inclined.

While not a course it may be worth checking out the webinar recording from Gurobi on stochastic models https://www.gurobi.com/events/solving-simple-stochastic-optimization-problems-with-gurobi/.  It includes downloadable materials.

Check this question too: Recommendations for OR video channels (YouTube etc.)

If you re starting your journey you may want to start from here: https://www.lindo.com/doc/online_help/lingo20_0/index.html?title_page2.htm. Also look at some of inventory models from Lindo.
